# Python - Pandas - Dataframe How to add variables to a column when using .count

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a new column that will count all ids but exclude a few rows of customers where the customer's ID has a certain prefix and has no repeat orders

```
df['newcolumn'] = df[(df.notnull['Date']) & (df['ID'].str.contains('prefix')) & (df['Repeat order'] == 'No')].groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).count()
```

I am getting below error

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Still no difference when I replaced [] with () to resolve above error

I also replaced `df[(df['Date'].notnull)` and got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'method' and 'bool' error`

Answer (score 0):

This is the coding equivalence of run-on sentence during English class. You were trying to stuff so many things into a single line that it's hard to tell where the problem is.

Break up you code:

```py
cond = (
  df['Date'].notnull()
  & df['ID'].str.contains('prefix')
  & df['Repeat order'].eq('No')
)
df['newcolumn'] = df[cond].groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).count()
```

---

NB: your original error was because of this:

```
df.notnull['Date']
```

`df.notnull` is a method. It's not subscriptable. You can execute the method and subscript the result:

```
df.notnull()['Date']
```

or you can extract a column from the data frame and run `notnull` on it:

```
df['Date'].notnull()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It makes sense. I got the error - Wrong number of items passed 19, placement implies 1